# html canvas: insert multiple images into separate canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I have multiple canvases, each with data-id attribute that is used to retrieve the dataURL in order to draw the image like so:

```
<canvas data-id='2' class='drawing-result>
```

The following will only put them all in the last canvas:

```
var $canvases = $(".drawing-result");
for (var i=0; i<$canvases.length; i++){
  var canvas = $canvases.get(i);
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  };
  // skipping the code for retrieving dataURL using data-id
  imageObj.src = dataURL;
```

I suspect it may have to do with shallow copying some things, but that can't be the case because I put var everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript's `var` variable declaration is function scoped, not block scoped. Your `context` is being overwritten every time the loop runs.

Instead of that for-loop, use jQuery's [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function:

```
$(".drawing-result").each(function (i, canvas) {
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  };
  // skipping the code for retrieving dataURL using data-id
  imageObj.src = dataURL;
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works. Do you know what's wrong with the code in the question?